# if else case in Android Espresso UI testing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

In the application, I am writing Espresso UI test for login flow in the app. I wrote the test and it works fine, but I have one case where I have problem.

In this application, users sometimes get bonuses when opening app (usually they don't but this is let's say 1:100 scenario)
In these situations, the pop up appears on the screen and my test fails because my code tries to trigger the button that is not visible (it is under the pop up).

I would like to write if-else in a test where I can for example check the visibility of the pop up close button. So if this is visible click on it and if it's not, then continue normally.

But I didn't find any if-else syntax in UI testing. Can someone with more experience in UI espresso testing help me with some advice here? THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two tests. One where bonus popup cannot appear and one where bonus popup always appears. This way so can test both behaviours.

You should not leave anything to a chance, and your issue is exactly the example of why not.

Comment: But pop up can always appear. This is the behaviour of the application, there is always possibility of pop up appearing on the screen. If I udnerstand you correctly when I start these test, one of them will fail and other will pass when I do the testing?

Comment: Under what conditions does our popup appear?  Some piece of code must control that.  break that pice of code into its own class.  Pass that class into the code that does the UI.  Then you can mock it to do exactly what you want for each test case-  either to show it or not to show it.

Comment: Pop up depends on backend. When backend decides to send bonus to user, we check it in the app and the pop up is shown.

Comment: To add on to the answer, the purpose of testing is examining specific behaviors within the code. Your responsibility at the start of a test is to set up the state of the code as a use case would dictate. Thus, one use case is login with no popup; the other is with popup. You need two tests to confirm both behaviors.

If you are unable to set the state in that way for a test, that can indicate poor coding patterns and choices. @GabeSechan provides an idea of how to go about rectifying that. Regarding backend actions, you can create a mock or fake to represent that behavior.

Comment: @Primož just to confirm, so there is no way of creating if-else in UI test code?

Comment: I never even tried doing if-else in a test. I guess it should be possible doing something with the regular if-else, but there is probably nothing in the framework for this because as was explained in the comments above; this is not how test are supposed to be written.

Comment: Ok thank you. Your answer is accepted

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Primož that you should not have an indeterminate test. But, if that is not possible, you could always use a try/catch with a specific exception to attempt to close the popup before the test.

Something like this might work (may need to tweak the catch depending on the exact exception throw when you do not have the popup view.

```kotlin
try {
  onView(withId(R.android.foo)).perform(click())
} catch (e: NoSuchViewException) {
 // code to be executed if view does not exist
}
```